# devtools::release() error - Space required after the Public Identifier

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to upload some updates to an R package I have on CRAN.  I've used devtools so far and without problems (thanks Hadley, you make our lives so much easier!) but upon calling devtools::release(), I get the following:

```
> devtools::release()
Space required after the Public Identifier
SystemLiteral " or ' expected
SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
Error: 1: Space required after the Public Identifier
2: SystemLiteral " or ' expected
3: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
```

I wish I could provide a more reproducible issue, but has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with your working directory or file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by digging into the `devtools` code.  The error occurred within the `devtools::dr_devtools()` step, in which the good doctor calls `rversions::r_release()`.  Reinstalling the `rversions` package did the trick.